# adding or delete componet based on button click in react

Tags: reactjs

this is my application. based on button click i want to load componet or delete component. but i am getting error attached snapshot. please help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would have been nice if your screenshots were not highlighted!

Comment: If your map cannot make his job, it's because your array is not defined (he not has his values). And why are you making 2 returns in one ?

Comment: @CorentindeMaupeou, thanks for ur help. as am new to React, i could not rectify.